# Is it possible to get name of the interface as a string?

Tags: typescript

Consider I have exported interface

```
export interface IMyAngularService{
}
```

When we register service or factory we usually use function name as a name of registered service or simply derivable string (e.g. 'ISomeService' -> 'SomeService');

Later I can decide to rename interface and would like dependencies descriptions to change automatically:

```
class MyController{

    static $inject = [
        dependency(nameof<ISomeService1>),
        dependency(nameof<ISomeService2>)
    ];

    constructor(...dependencies){
    }
}
```

where `dependency` function conventionally gets service name from interface name. Thus whenever name of `ISomeService1` is changed, resulting JavaScript contains changed strings.

Comment: It's legal to have a `var` with the same name as an interface, so you could just write `var IMyAngularService = 'MyAngularService';` next to the interface declaration

Comment: @Ryan But you declare interfaces inside modules which become IEFEs. So variable is either inaccessible or must be global. Whereas exported interfaces are accessible from anywhere but do not live traces in JS.

Comment: What's wrong with `export var` ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is not possible. TypeScript doesn't generate any code for interfaces and there's nothing like the `nameof` operator.

Comment: What a shame. `nameof IMyAngularService` would appear to be trivial to implement at compiletime to expand to `"IMyAngularService"`; that would save some refactoring effort.

Answer (score 14):

You can if you map all your interfaces to their name, like below.

```
interface Blueberry { strawberry: boolean; }
interface Car { vehicle: number; }

interface Interfaces {
    Blueberry: Blueberry;
    Car: Car;
}
```

Then you can get the names of an interface like so:

```
export type RemoveNeverProps<T> = {
    [K in Exclude<
        keyof T, ({
            [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? P : never
        })[keyof T]>
    ]: T[K]
};

export type IncludeProp<T extends object, E> =
    RemoveNeverProps<{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends E ? T[K] : never }>;

type Nameof<I extends Interfaces[keyof Interfaces]> =
    keyof IncludeProp<Interfaces, I>;
```

Comment: this along with the [ts-simple-nameof](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-simple-nameof) library from @IRCraziestTaxi are a really nice combo to keep me from typeos, thanks!

Comment: it will be nice if the compiler does that for us... add all interfaces in one system class so we can find them..